# I can't dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu 14.04, grub seems to be missing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

Today I turned on my computer and got a message stating that no boot option was available. I restarted and it went straight into Windows 10. Now when I restart I can't get to my grub options with Ubuntu 14.04

What could I do? I haven't done anything so I don't mess up things before asking.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Was it working before or is this the first time trying to boot into Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Did you update Windows 10 to the Anniversary update? The Anniversary update probably bombed grub.

Comment: It was working perfectly before, even after the anniversary update. On friday I remember installing a few updates though, that may have caused it.

Comment: Also, I entered my bios settings and I can see the Legacy and UEFi settings, it is set to prompt for my OS before booting.